# How to get firebase's user's posted data without knowing user id? Is it even possible?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building an app with React.js in which a user can create a certain poll, which is saved to firebase. And user himself can see the menu of all HIS created polls. The data is organised in firebase like this:

```
Users:  
    -XXXXXX:    (the user UID)
        -YYYYYY:    (firebase's random string name, that represents a single poll)
                options: [1,2,3],
                question: "What color is the sun?",
                values: ["yellow","red","orange"]

        -YYYYYY: ...   (another poll the user created)
        -YYYYYY: ...  (third poll the user created)
```

Now, each poll is at a different link, which is /YYYYYY

On the poll link website, I'm trying to get the poll data for the current poll. The issue I'm having is getting the data itself IF the user is not logged-in (I want anyone to be able to vote).

Is there a way of "skipping" the user who created the poll, and reach the poll YYYYYY and its data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you organise you polls in a different way, the user would be a field of your poll (e.g. an author filed containing the user UID).

Anyway you can still access the poll, by querying the `users` collection with `var usersRef = db.collection("users");`, as explained here https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data.
You can then iterate on the response for all XXXXXX users and each YYYYYY polls until you find the YYYYYY id you are interested in.

Comment: Both answers are great! Thank you, I'm working on it

Answer (score 1):

If you know the poll's key (`YYYYYY` in your sample), you can load it by:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("users");
var query = ref.orderByKey().equalTo("YYYYYY");
query.once("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.key, snapshot.val());
});
```

Comment: I did what you suggested, with the correct YYYYY. But the app is not logging any data, or errors  (I have done it in componentDidMount())